# Running Openstack on 3 nodes

Tags: server, juju, maas, cloud

Is it possible to run the openstack cloud over 3 nodes (initially, with a further node to follow at a later date)? The servers are all quad core xeon, 12gb ram and 2x1TB disks.

I am currently looking at virtualising a very small network, however we do not have the money or facilities to sustain the advertised minimum of 6 servers to run openstack. Also, money is a limit as this is for a not for profit organisation.

I would rather run openstack than VMWare as it means it will operate as a cluster, unlike ESXi which will not.

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-cloud - Step 4

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is Yes, but do not expect anything spectacular or consider it as an industrial deployment. Deployments like these are more suited for test environments unless you'r up for some serious "infrastructure hacking". Also **MaaS & JuJu combined are deployment methodologies. They put software on machines. What you do with it is up to you, so you still have to go through the Openstack Operations guide and documentation to get a feel of what's going on.**

Deploying services from the cmd-line in juju does allow to co-locate services in machines although you should be careful with how you mix them up.

```
juju deploy-service -e myMaaS mysql--to 1
```

In detail, you have to consider the deployment of the following collection of services throughout your stack, for it to work,even though **just barely.**

- MaaS Server (1st Server) (Typical installation)
- The JuJu bootstrap node (2nd Server) or machine 0 in  JuJu style.
- Openstack Stack (3rd Server) or machine 1 in JuJu style.

  - RabbitMQ
  - MySQL
  - Keystone
  - Glance
  - Cinder
  - Keystone
  - Openstack Dashboard
  - Nova-Cloud-Controller
  - Nova-Compute

Note:I have deployed a test-stack like that so it does work,but it's a test environment.

However, this is pretty much a huge waste of resources, even if the services are scalable.

The alternatives to these would be.

a)Deploy the openstack manually without MaaS & JuJu or with some other DevOp tool e.g saltstack.

**b)Slice the servers. Use some-type of virtualization to create VMs that are in the same network as MaaS (with bridged adapters and PXE booting capabilities). By doing that you will be able to add the machines in the MaaS Cluster even if they are in the same physical machine as MaaS. Even VMs count as standalone nodes and you can use them with JuJu.**

Since you are asking in Ubuntu,I'll assume you are trying to squeeze it with MaaS & JuJu although MaaS is more suited for the management of a large number of physical machines.

So let's go with 
b)Slice the servers.
  The considerations you'd have to keep in mind are the following.

- MaaS doesn't need a whole server of that caliber on it's own. You are better off slicing the first server to handle non-openstack services.
- The JuJu Node. Since it won't be doing much state management it doesn't need a standalone physical node on it's own. It is better suited to live on the first server.
- Add any other management service you might require on the first server's VMs through JuJu or without it.
- The Openstack Services. You can get away with support services living on the same server in small deployments. You could cram all but the nova-compute on the 2nd physical server.
- Nova-Compute is the service that will expose virtualization HW resources to your cloud and is better suited for using an entire physical server. Save the 3rd server as a whole for the nova-compute. In addition, adding more Compute Resources equals adding the new physical server and clustering it under Nova-Compute from JuJu
- Cinder handles the Storage for openstack so it needs to use an LVM or SDX volume where it's installed to expose it to the cloud. Make sure you have partitioned/saved a dedicated volume array for the Cinder. Also from checking your HDs...you really need more.

The are more considerations to take into deploying the Openstack stack,such as actually proxying the dashboard to an apache-server,a backup location,not drowning the keystone server (the last one sees quite a lot of traffic).

In short.

- First Server (Sliced)

  - MaaS  - Outside of JuJu
  - JuJu Bootstrap Node - Machine 0
  - Generic VM for some non-stack service. Machine N
- Second Server (Doesn't need to be sliced) Machine N+1

  - RabbitMQ
  - MySQL
  - Glance
  - Cinder
  - Nova-Cloud-Controller
  - Keystone
  - Openstack-Dashboard
- Third Server - Machine N+2

  - Nova-Compute

Hope that helps to get you started.